# Implementing horizontal scrolling images using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling

I want to implement Horizontal scrolling images using JQuery. Basically I want to repeat animate() infinite times. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testDiv">
    <h1 class="heading">Test Text</h1>
    <ul class="reasons">
        <li class="item">
           <img>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <img>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
           <img>
        </li>  
    </ul>       
</div>
```

*JQuery:**

```
let itemsLength = $('.item').length;
```

$(document).ready(loop());

function loop(){

```
for (i = 1; i <= itemsLength; i++) {
      $('.reasons').animate({"scrollLeft": "+=150px"},"slow", function(){
                    loop();
                          }/*function*/     
                          });/*animate*/
        }/*for*/
    }/*function loop()*/
```

CSS:

```
.testDiv {
    margin-top: 2vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 40;        
}

.reasons {
    height: 200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I have tried using `$('.reasons').append($('.item')[0]);`. This just appends the list item but does not scroll. I think there the scrollLeft value needs to be changed but don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure, what you are trying to do, but maybe this idea will help you somehow:

```
  function loop(){
    for (i = 1, j=0; i <= itemsLength; i++, j+=150) 
    {
       $('.reasons').animate({"scrollLeft": j},"slow", function(){
                                              
       });
    }
    loop();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to scroll the images to the left horizontally in an infinite loop. Your code scrolls to the left but because value of j again initializes to 0, it scrolls the whole ul to the right and then left again.It goes to and fro.

Comment: Any idea..how can I implement left scrolling images using jQuery ?